# Result check with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When we are checking one active record result is empty or not, what will be
   way which have more performance.

```
pc_count = Property.select("id").where('property_category_id = ?', 5).limit(1)

if pc_count.blank?
  #
end

if pc_count[0]
  #
end
```

In two ways i have tried this **pc_count.blank?** or **pc_count[0]**, because i heard that blank will take extra query, but when i tried that in console i couldn't see that any extra call

Answer (score 2):

Try **exists**

which will be like.

```
  Person.exists?(5)
  Person.exists?('5')
  Person.exists?(:name => "David")
  Person.exists?(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"])
  Person.exists?
```

refer: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F

Answer (score 1):

No, both your versions do not produce another query.

It depends what you are doing with `pc_count`:

1.) You are using that `id` somewhere later, then use either of your methods (i prefer `.blank?`)

2.) You only need this for the this check. Then I would do

```
 Property.select("id").where('property_category_id = ?', 5).limit(1).count
```

because there will be no model created and you can just test `count == 0`